# Regex with iframe in Yahoo! Pipes

Tags: regex, iframe, yahoo-pipes

I'm building a Yahoo! Pipe to pull an RSS feed from Reddit which links to some content in the description.  I'm using a regex to match the href attribute of the anchor link in an `item.description` field.  The regex I'm using is:

`^.+?href="([^"]+)">\[link\].+?$`

As a test, I set the replace to simply:

`$1`

and I see that the entire description field has been replaced with the URL.  So far, so good.

I then put the following in the replace field.  The idea being to iframe the content that's linked to:

`Content: <iframe src="$1">no iframe support</iframe> End`

What I get out however is:

`Content: no iframe support End`

I've confirmed that this is also coming through in the pipe's output and not just in the Yahoo! Pipes debug console.

I've so far tried replacing my angle brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities.  I've tried wrapping the entire thing in a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block and still, I get nothing.  If I break my iframe tag by removing an angle bracket, the broken content comes through fine, but if I have a well-formed iframe element, it vanishes, leaving the "no iframe support" text.  Am I doing something wrong here, or is Yahoo! *actively preventing* me from using iframe tags in my generated pipe?  A cursory search on Google isn't turning up anything related to this.

The pipe in question is here:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2ba41448cadd2347d86f377efd3d199f

Comment: I've accepted an answer relating to the "is Yahoo! preventing this" and it's more or less "yes", but I'd love it if someone could figure out a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Pipes FAQ Question](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=troubleshooting#q13) "Why does Pipes Strip <object> and <embed> tags... ?" shows that a certain amount of sanitization is performed, by placing content (at least *certain content*) into an iframe for the safety of RSS consumers - though it does not state it specifically, this probably also removes other iframes in order to avoid nesting and other work-arounds.

Yahoo is big enough I would doubt they have a week sanitizer, but an extremely long shot is that you might be able to fool it by nesting the iframe in a bunch of other tags (again I doubt this will work). Also depending upon which step does the sanitization, perhaps adding part of the tag in one step, then adding another part somewhere else might work (yet again, doubt overwhelms me)

Not sure what else to suggest, other than getting something else to consume and transform your RSS a little bit more (by fixing otherwise broken tags??) - but that's what you're using pipes for to begin with, isn't it? Idunno...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Pipes has an fanatical devotion to the RSS spec and the spec says the description field is plain text only. HTML etc is supposed to go in the content:encoded field, not that I've had much luck getting pipes to do that.